# invite friends to facebook

Tags: facebook

I succeeded popping the multi-friend selector but when you click on skip button or after sending invitations it'll redirect you to action tag value specified in fb:request-form however, my application is iframe based not fbml so when I enter a relative url it wont work and it displays a message that the url is not valid and when I enter the absolute url it displays the appropriate redirect page in a second iframe inside the app. iframe. I tried using target="_top" but it didn't work. any ideas?